# What does BOP: CP: SA mean?

Tags: finance

If I look at [this time series](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/nationalaccounts/balanceofpayments/timeseries/ikbi/) from the Office for National Statistics, the title reads

> Total Trade (TT): WW: Imports: BOP: CP: SA

I can't find any kind of explanation for these acronyms. I think I can figure out:

BOP: balance of payments

WW: worldwide

SA: seasonally adjusted (maybe?)

But what about CP? No idea even how to use Google to find this one out.

Comment: ?? Current Prices ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See
https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/nationalaccounts/uksectoraccounts/methodologies/chainlinkingmethodsusedwithintheuknationalaccounts

SA = Seasonally Adjusted

NSA = Not Seasonally Adjusted

SAAR = Seasonally Adjusted at an Annual Rate (obviously different from YOY, year-on-year; or QOQ, quarter-on-quarter)

CP = Current Prices (ie nominal value, not adj for inflation)

KP = Constant Prices (ie real terms, adj for inflation). Note that "inflation" here is not CPI or PPI, but the price index associated with that particular series. So "real terms" can mean very different things comparing eg precious metals mining to semiconductors!

CVM = Chain-linked Volume Measure (ie de-priced and compounded).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you got this from the [ONS](https://www.ons.gov.uk) @noob2 is correct, see their [answer](https://www.ons.gov.uk/aboutus/transparencyandgovernance/freedomofinformationfoi/cpnsa):

> You asked
>
> I saw in one of your tables the wording CP NSA. I would like to know the meaning of those letters.
>
> We said
>
> In response to your question about the wording "CP NSA" included in the PSF tables, the meaning of these are:
>
> CP: Current Prices, where data are presented in terms of the prices of the time period being estimated (that is, not adjusted for inflation).

Unfortunately, I could find a full list with abbreviations.